# Can i check if an array e.g. just holds integers in ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays, loops

Title, i think is self declaring. I am kind of a java-developer and wanna ensure that my array holds just integer values. I know everything in ruby is a object. I find it inconvenient to loop through the array and make checks at every element. Is there any shortcut to this in ruby?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use [`Enumerable#all?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-all-3F) with a block. Integer numbers are instances of class [Integer](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Integer.html) in ruby.

```
[1, 2, 3].all? {|i| i.is_a?(Integer) } # => true
[1, 2, 3, '4'].all? {|i| i.is_a?(Integer) } # => false
```

Comment: *Small* integers are Fixnum in Ruby. This won't work with large integers. To cover all int numbers, use the Integer class itself: `puts [1, 2, 3, 4444444444].all? {|i| i.is_a? Integer }`