# getting differences between values in an array

Tags: ruby, arrays

I want to write an Array method in ruby that takes the successive values in the array and returns their differences as a new array (unshifting a '0' in at the beginning).

So feeding the array [4,7,11,16] into the method returns a new array [4,3,4,5].

1) does such a method already exist?

If not, then I think I know how to write it. However,

2) does a method already exist which allows me to test the input array and make sure it only consists of integers and/or floats?

Again, if not, I think I know how to write one.

Comment: Why the rush to select the first answer offered? You are fortunate to have received other answers, as applying the green checkmark often discourages such. (Go, Bears!)

Comment: Go Bears! -- and thank you for your message. I'm a newbie & still learning to use stackoverflow. I could have waited, and will do so next time. Unfortunately, I cannot express my appreciation for the other answers because I'm not allowed to upvote them yet. Any suggestions?

Comment: My advice: get rep. You can express appreciation in comments, but do so selectively, maintaining a high standard. Also, read this [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the first method, I am not aware of any such method in the Ruby `Array` class.

Regarding the second one, you can do it as explained [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12158954/368167):

```
your_array.all? {|i| i.is_a? Numeric }
```

Comment: For "integer and/or floats" use `Numeric` not `Fixnum`.

Answer (score 3):

```
p [4,7,11,16].unshift(0).each_cons(2).map{|a,b| b-a} # => [4, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 2):

Keep it simple:

```
arr = [4,7,11,16]

last = 0
arr.map { |e| new=e-last; last=e; new }
  #=> [4, 3, 4, 5]
```

Another way:

```
a = [arr.first]
enum = arr.each
loop do
  a << -enum.next + enum.peek
end
a
  #=> [4, 3, 4, 5]
```

[Enumerator#peek](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerator.html#method-i-peek) raises a `StopIteration` exception when `enum` is at its last element. [Kernel#loop](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-loop) handles the exception by breaking from the loop.